# pytube urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytube

I get an error when i try to download  a video from youtube with pytube.

```py
from pytube import YouTube

yt = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0')
stream = yt.streams.first()
stream
stream.download()
```

The error says "Forbidden", but fetching e.g. with `curl` from the same URL seems to work just fine. What could be wrong here?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mr. jarvis/Desktop/youtube/youtube.py", line 7, in <module>
    stream.download()
  File "C:\Users\Mr. jarvis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pytube\streams.py", line 217, in download
    bytes_remaining = self.filesize
  File "C:\Users\Mr. jarvis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pytube\streams.py", line 164, in filesize
    headers = request.get(self.url, headers=True)
  File "C:\Users\Mr. jarvis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 21, in get
    response = urlopen(url)
  File "C:\Users\Mr. jarvis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Mr. jarvis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\Mr. jarvis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\Mr. jarvis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Mr. jarvis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Mr. jarvis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: I received the same error on trying the tutorial code from the docs. I checked the Issues for pytube on github, and others are experiencing [the same issue](https://github.com/nficano/pytube/issues/408). [This Issue thread](https://github.com/nficano/pytube/issues/399) on the github has some solutions that might work for you. Google changes YouTube frequently, so you can probably bet that this is a recurring problem with this library. The single `stream` line in your code can be removed from the script, as it only prints the variable's data when used in the Python REPL.

Comment: thank you for your help , and  let me know if u found the solution

Answer (score 0):

Experienced the same problem.  I found unfinished downloaded file in the project folder.  After deleting the unfinished downloaded file and running stream.download() again, it worked. So maybe worth checking.

pytube version 12.0.0

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: on newer versions change "ANDROID_MUSIC" to "ANDROID" on line 223, same file

I edited a file in PyTube and got it working (altho a little slower)
for me the path to the file was:

C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pytube\inntertube.py

Edit the file called "innertube.py"

on line 78 try replacing client='ANDROID' with client='WEB'
[Image of where to find file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twfas.png)

[Image of where to edit file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vMHX.png)